# Is there any way to support IPV6 with common-vfs2 for ftp or cifs

Tags: java, ftp, ipv6, cifs, vfs

I want to fetch files with FTP or CIFS protocol in IPV6 network env, but I find that common-vfs2 does not support IPV6.

Is there any way to resolve that?

Or any replaced Jar for common-vfs2

Thanks a lot

Comment: really? may you provide the link where you have found this issue?

Answer (score 1):

From the ticket [VFS-524](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/VFS-524), looks like commons-vfs2 does not support IPv6 yet.
You can use JSch SFTP as a replacement, I have tried JSch version 0.1.54, it works. Example code as below (Just example, please modify to make it robust):

```
JSch ssh = new JSch();
ssh.setKnownHosts("/home/the_user/known_hosts");
session = ssh.getSession("the_user_name", "the_ipv6_ip", 22);
session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "yes");
session.setPassword("the_password");
session.connect();
channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
channel.connect();
ChannelSftp sftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
sftp.get("the_remote_file_path", "local_file_path");
```